# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to run a code to create tables in oracle database.I am using **Python** **3.6.5** and **Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0** in windows 64 bit.

con=cx_Oracle.connect(config.connection)

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are unable to connect to the Oracle DB. As pointed out [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-connect-to-Oracle-10-g-database-from-python):

> You need to install cx_Oracle extension for python and make sure environment variables are correctly set

In addition, see that the credentials in `config.connection` are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the latest major release of the cx_Oracle driver doesn't need Oracle libraries by default, so configuration is easier.  The driver got renamed to python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

cx_Oracle 6+ needs to be using Oracle 11.2+ libraries.  It seems you are linking it with your 10g DB libraries. You can install 11.2 libraries using the free [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html), set PATH to include them, and then connect to your 10g database - but don't stuff up PATH for other applications that need the 10g libraries. You'll probably need to use something like a BAT script to set PATH and then call python.

The Oracle 11.2 libraries must be the same 32-bit or 64-bit as Python is.

If there's anything unclear in https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html then log an issue on the cx_Oracle project at https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues